# Google Maps Marker Clusterer not showing cluster icons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have a Google Map with a set of markers on. I'm trying to add MarkerClusterer to it to simplify the view.  Overall, doing so should be pretty easy from what I've seen online but when I try it, my map doesn't show any markers, clusters or anything.  My code is below:

```
function calculateCenter() {
            center = map.getCenter()
        }

        let center
        let worldCenter = new window.google.maps.LatLng(32.249974, 5.800781)
        let mapOptions = {
            center: worldCenter,
            zoom: 3,
            scrollwheel: false
        }

        let map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('.banner--map--parks'), mapOptions)
        let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
        let markers = []

        map.addListener('idle', _ => {
            calculateCenter()
        })

        fetch('/api/parks.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            data.forEach(park => {
                if (park.lat && park.lng) {
                    let title = park.name
                    let position = new google.maps.LatLng(park.lat, park.lng)
                    let icon = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers/master/images/marker_blue.png'
                    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: position
                        title: title,
                        icon: icon,
                        // map: map
                    })

                    let parkIWContent = '<div class="iw"><a href="/parks/' + park.id + '">' + park.name + '</a></div>'

                    marker.addListener('click', (function(marker, parkIWContent) { 
                        return function() {
                            infoWindow.setContent(parkIWContent);
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                            // map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(park.lat, park.lng))
                        };
                    })(marker, parkIWContent))

                    markers.push(marker)
                }
            })
        })

        console.log(markers)

        let markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers)

        map.addListener("click", _ => {
            infoWindow.close()
        })
```

As you can see, at one point I did output the array of markers and they do all show up in the console but still fail to show on the map.

Can anyone spot any issues with the code that may be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue and includes debugging details. What does your javascript console say? How are you loading the maps and clustering libraries? Does the map show at all? Do you see the markers if you uncomment `// map: map`? etc.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I'll try to get an example up on codepen but some answers before then:  Yes, markers show if I uncomment that line. GMaps is loaded via a script tag. Marker clustered is loaded via NPM with `import MarkerClusterer from '@google/markerclustererplus'`. Yes the map shows.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually managed to solve this.   I needed to move the Marker Clusterer inside the `.then` in order for it to work.